# Simple HTML DOM getting td content from tr where specific content is

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Html what I am grabbing looks like this

```
<div id="table"><table>
<tr><td>Clubname</td><td>15</td><td>30</td></tr>
<tr><td>Clubname 2</td><td>15</td><td>30</td></tr>
<tr><td>Clubname 3</td><td>15</td><td>30</td></tr>
</table></div>
```

What i want is to find the tr where Clubname 2 is in and get the data from td[1] and td[2] and output this.

I want this done with simple_html_dom.php

What I already have is

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('webpage.html');
foreach($html->find('div#table') as $e)
echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

How to find the specific clubname and get the specific content from the td's from same tr?

=================================================================================

Okay thanks, what I did now is like you told me, only with variable, because later I want to use a variable.

```
<?php
    $clubname = 'Ajax';
    require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');         
    $result = array();
    $limit = 2; //you need only the next two sibling

    $dom = phpQuery::newDocumentFile('http://soccer.gijsve.nl/test2.php');        
    $match = $dom->find('td:contains("'.$clubname.'")');        
    while( 0 < count( $match = $match->next() ) && ( 0 < $limit-- )  ){
            $result[] = $match->text();
    }
    var_dump($result);

?>
```

What I want now is to select the first td (td before the match) and the fourth and fifth for example. Because I need to know the scored goals, the points and the rank. See http://soccer.gijsve.nl/test2.php for the table I am grabbing.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal: OP provided sample code?

Comment: Yes it is sample code, this is the real code: http://soccer.gijsve.nl/test2.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you an other simple DOM tool:
     http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/
As i expreienced it is a bit faster, and the selectors working better. This project is not finished jet. But the dom reading section works well.
The selectors working like in jQuery ;)

```
<?php
    require('phpquery/phpQuery.php');         
    $result = array();
    $limit = 2; //you need only the next two sibling

    $dom = phpQuery::newDocumentFile('webpage.html');        
    $match = $dom->find('td:contains("Clubname 2")');        
    while( 0 < count( $match = $match->next() ) && ( 0 < $limit-- )  ){
            $result[] = $match->text();
    }
    var_dump($result);

    // other example:
    $match = $dom->find('td:contains("Clubname 2")');        
    $loses = $match->siblings('.loses')->text(); //matches the siblings of the $match element, and has loses class
    $wins = $match->siblings('.wins')->text(); //matches the siblings of the $match element, and has wins class

?>
```

This works on your sample html, and the full html what you commented.

With simple_html_dom you could search for text, as a text 'tag':

```
$textlist = $html->find('text');
```

This returns the all of text blocks, and you should run foreach the $textlist, and if the elemnt's html equals what you find, you save it to a variable, and step back to the parent of this (in the full html, the second parent) than step to next sibling, and again next sibling, i think is more complicated, than with phpQuery.

Comment: It is new for me to grab html with php and do something with it, so I'm learning it. I will post in the Openingpost what I did. I have one more question: what if I want the td before the clubname and the fourth td and the fifth, for example.

Comment: step with next, as many as you need.
If the 4th next you need:
$fourthNext = $match->next()->next()->next()-next(); 
if you need the previuus element $prev = $match->prev();
There is a way to add selector to the next and prev function. As i saw in the full code you can navigate with:
$loses = $match->next('.loses');
or if you not sure is prev or next, you can use $loses = $match->siblings('.loses') //this match the sibling has the loses class

Comment: I will play with this further, but it is all clear. Thanks for the answer and your time

Comment: Okay I made this http://soccer.gijsve.nl/phpquery/test.php?name=Volendam&divisie=5 it works all great with your help. One more question: match is case sensitive, can we configure it not to be?

Comment: The :contains is case insensitive, the attribute, tag and class selectors are case sensitive. the sensivity is not configurable :(

Comment: Kovge for some reason it is working not case sensitive right now.. http://soccer.gijsve.nl/phpquery/test.php?name=Volendam&divisie=5 and http://soccer.gijsve.nl/phpquery/test.php?name=volendam&divisie=5 good news

Comment: I tried out with tags, the TD selector did not match for td tags, in contains it is not case sensitive. This librari using XPATH, so the behaviour of the selectors like in XPATH. When i use this lib, i always convert to lowercase the xml string (if that the case sensitivity is not relevant in the xml).
And if you have affinity, you could change this behaviur in the code of the library.

Answer (score 1):

Phpquery also has sibling selectors which make life easier:

```
$dom->find('td:contains("Clubname 2") + td')->text(); # 15
$dom->find('td:contains("Clubname 2") + td + td')->text(); # 30
$dom->find('td:contains("Clubname 2") ~ td')->text(); # 15 30
```